# Multi target prediction

Tags: python, r

I am working on traffic violation data set which contains 36 columns(variable). I have two dependent variables out of this.

Example

```
violation id, description, age, sex , alcohol, type of vehicle, violation level, accident
```

id, description, age, sex    alcohol     vehicle     violation level Accident

```
  120   speed      28    M       Yes         car             severe       yes                                                                                                                                      
  122   win-tint   35    F       No         truck            Medium       no                          
  123   left-turn  26    M       No          car             light        no                                                                                                                 
  124  failure-veh 28    M       No          car             severe       yes
```

The dependent variables are "violation level" and "accident".

violation level has 3 classes -- sever
                                 medium
                                 light

Accident has 2 levels -- Yes
                         No

I want to predict both violation level and accident. I think this can be multitarget prediction.

Can someone help me which algorithm is good for this? I have seen some articles suggesting scikit- multiout put classification and neural network with multiple out put layers.

Or Can I go ahead with two models?

1. predicting the traffic violation level.
2. Predicting the accidents using the violation levels.

Basically I am trying to predict violation levels and then predicting how these violations contribute to accidents.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to count `violation level` while predicting `accident` and vice-versa?

Comment: I want to include violation levels when predicting the accidents. When predicting violation levels, I am not considering accidents.

Comment: Generally if you want to predict a certain y, based on the output of another predictor you should be careful and use a procedure called Stacking (https://www.quora.com/What-is-stacking-in-machine-learning)
If you don't, you are violating the integrity of your data and your cross-validation is no longer a representative of your true performance.

Comment: I am new to machine learning. In stacking method, suppose, I use violation level as target variable for my trained models. Can I use the output of this to predict the other target variable(accident)? I have seen stacking examples where they train data on one target variable with different algorithms. Then combine the output of those algorithms to predict the same target.

Comment: Can multi-layer neural network does the same task?